# Proper way to return IQueryable using WCF Data Service and EF

Tags: entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

So I want to return some data, and I'm using WCF Data Services and Entity Framework, that looks like:

```
public class MyWcfDataService : DataService<MyEFModel>
{
   [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   public IQueryable<GetMyListEF> GetMyList()
   {
       using (MyEfModel context = this.CurrentDataSource)
       {
           return context.GetMyListEF().ToList().AsQueryable();
       }
   }
}
```

As you can see I'm casting to a list, then to queryable. If I only cast `AsQueryable()`, I won't be able to Read the data because the connection has closed (due to deferred execution of AsQueryable).

So my question is, is there a better way? Is the `using` statement even needed? The data can sometimes be 100k rows, so casting to a list uses a fair amount of memory. It would also be nice to really take advantage of deferred execution and only return a true IQueryable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the using, in fact it's better not to have it. The WCF Data Service will dispose the CurrentDataSource at the end of the request. So just use it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've always been told that whenever something implements IDisposable, it should be Disposed. Can you provide a link to the documentation for the workflow of how DataService works in the manner you've described?

Comment: You need to use the using on all IDisposable instances which your code owns. The data source is owned by the data service object. It's created shortly after the data service object is created and is disposed after the request has been processed. Unfortunately I can't find a link which would describe this right now.