# Does DataService implement IDisposable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

Here is an example service:

```
public class MyWcfDataService : DataService<MyEFModel>
{
   [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   public IQueryable<GetMyListEF> GetMyList()
   {
      using (MyEfModel context = this.CurrentDataSource)
      {
          return context.GetMyListEF().ToList().AsQueryable();
      }
   }
}
```

Should I be using the `using` statement? It kinda makes `IQueryable` pointless since I have to cast it to a List first (I do this because other methods call the `GetMyList` method and without casting to a list first, the data is gone [because of deferred execution])

I thought I've read somewhere (can't find the link now) that WCF Data Services don't implement IDisposable. If this is true then the `using` statement is pointless.

Comment: If it didn't expose a Dispose method then it wouldn't compile with a `using` statement.

Comment: `ToList()` iterates over the whole input sequence. Calling `AsQueryable()` on that doesn't make much sense, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with this:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public IQueryable<GetMyListEF> GetMyList()
{
    return this.CurrentDataSource.GetMyListEF();
}
```

The `using` statement isn't needed because the WCF Data Service will dispose the `CurrentDataSource` at the end of the request. Using `IQueryable` also allows utilization of lazy loading aka deferred execution.

Here is another post on this:
[Proper way to return IQueryable using WCF Data Service and EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190956/proper-way-to-return-iqueryable-using-wcf-data-service-and-ef)

Answer (score 2):

The `using` statement will cause your `CurrentDataSource` to be disposed at the end of the `using` block, not when the `DataService` is disposed. Therefore it's not a question of whether the `DataService` is `IDisposable` (it isn't), but whether `MyEfModel` is disposable (it is). As Mr. Disappointment points out, the compiler would prevent your using the `using` statement if this were not the case.

This means that the `using` block is best used when you create a new object. For example:

```
using (MyEfModel context = this.GetNewDataSource()) {...}
```

That way you don't run into the possibility that someone will try accessing `CurrentDataSource` after the using block and encountering an exception.

Regarding your other point about IQueryable and such, I haven't typically seen WCF methods implement `IQueryable<>`, since they're consumed over a network connection. Usually `IEnumerable<>` is preferred. And you're not "casting" your query to a List, as that would imply it was already in a list. You are *evaluating* the query to *create* a List. Then you might *cast* that list to an *IEnumerable* or *IQueryable* because List implements those interfaces.